# Downloadable Norwegian dictionary with verb conjugations?

Tags: dictionary, norwegian

Apologies as this doesn't perfectly fit into linguistics but there isn't a Norwegian Stack Exchange site where I think this would be a more appropriate question.

Is anyone aware of a downloadable Norwegian dictionary that includes verb conjugations? I'm looking for [this](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?&D1=25&T1=komme) except in the form of a dictionary.

Specifically, I'm writing a program for myself that creates flashcards. While I can scrape websites for it that is generally frowned on, not particularly fast, and often outright against a website's terms of service. I would like to purchase a dictionary from which I can then read the information.

Comment: Are you looking for just conjugations, or also translations? The conjugations themselves should be possible to retrieve from various of [Språkbankens lexical databases](https://www.nb.no/sprakbanken/en/resource-catalogue/?_search=ordbank), but I’m not sure if those have definitions, and if they do, I’m pretty sure they’re only in Norwegian.

Comment: Just conjugations - definitions would be convenient just because it's a bit less programming, but there are plenty of sources for definitions that I can pull in and correlate